# Bad magic number in super-block

Tags: boot, fsck

I've launched some software on my computer, and it got stuck, so I hard shut down the computer. When I powered it back on, I was directed to `initramfs`, and got the error:

```
fsck exited with status code 12
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed.
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires manual fsck
```

I booted the computer from USB in live mode and ran the following command:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1
```

and got the error:

```
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1
```

I don't have any problem to lose all the data on the disk in order to solve this. Could it be a hardware issue?

How would installing Windows affect this situation?

Answer (score 1):

`dumpe2fs` is specific to the `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` family of file systems, so if you use something else, then that would complain in exactly the way described that this is not an Extended file system.

If it is one of the `ext` family, then running `fsck` will clean this up nicely, as `ext` stores multiple copies of the superblock in different spots of the disk, and `fsck` would just use another one and restore the one in the beginning.

If it is a different file system, `fsck` still has a good chance of working, although a lot of the newer file systems are not that resilient anymore.

Last but not least, check that the device names are the same when booting from a live stick -- it is quite likely that the USB stick as the boot device is now the first one found, so it is named `sda`, and the harddisk is now named `sdb`. Use `fdisk` to look at the partition table, whether it matches what you expect, especially the size of the disk and the partitions.